# Multivariate Copulas and uniroot error in R

Tags: r

I am trying to construct a multivariate copula method with time series (19 observations) for 7 risk indicators. First I would like to find which is the most suitable copula I should use for this dataset. I would expect that the best fit would be the Gumbel method with survival function but still want to make sure that I am at the right track. For this, I am using Vinecopula package in R. To begin with, I convert my data to uniform marginals using rank method with the function:

```
umr= apply(dataset,2,rank)/(nrow(dataset)+1)
```

Then, I try to run the following function:

```
st_rvine= RVineStructureSelect(dataset, familyset = NA, type = 0, selectioncrit = "AIC", indeptest = FALSE, level = NA, progress = FALSE, weights = NA, treecrit = "tau",rotations = TRUE, se=FALSE, presel = TRUE, method = "mle",cores = 1)
```

After this however I get the following error:

> Error in uniroot(function(x) tau - frankTau(x), lower = 0 + .Machine$double.eps^0.5,  : 
>     f() values at end points not of opposite sign

I still haven't found what I may be doing wrong. Can anyone guide me on this please? Is there a mistake on my formulas or there a step that I am missing?

Thank you in advance.